# Property has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm getting the below error while trying to validate the schema - v7 draft. Appreciate your help in resolving this error.

I'm trying to build the schema based on the conditional enum value from header. The attribute 'salary' type needs to vary based on the condition choose in the header.

ERROR

**Property 'salary' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.**

JSON schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "EmployeeHeader": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "empType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "FULLTIME",
            "CONTRACT"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "empType"
      ]
    },
    "EmployeeDetail": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "workInfo": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "jobtitle": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 200
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "jobtitle"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "workInfo"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "minItems": 1
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "EmployeeHeader": {
        "properties": {
          "empType": {
            "const": "FULLTIME"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "EmployeeDetail": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "workInfo": {
              "properties": {
                "salary": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "regular": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 0,
                      "maximum": 1000000,
                      "exclusiveMaximum": false,
                      "multipleOf": 0.01
                    },
                    "bonus": {
                      "type": "number",
                      "minimum": 0,
                      "maximum": 1000000,
                      "exclusiveMaximum": false,
                      "multipleOf": 0.01
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "EmployeeDetail": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "workInfo": {
              "properties": {
                "salary": {
                  "type": "number",
                  "minimum": 0,
                  "maximum": 1000000,
                  "exclusiveMaximum": false,
                  "multipleOf": 0.01
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "EmployeeHeader",
    "EmployeeDetail"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

SAMPLE PAYLOAD

```
{
  "EmployeeHeader": {
    "empType": "FULLTIME"
  },
  "EmployeeDetail": [
    {
      "workInfo": {
        "jobtitle": "Software Engineer",
        "salary": {
          "regular": 4000,
          "bonus": 5000
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't have to keep adding $schema properties at every level. Those will all be ignored by the draft7 implementation.

Comment: Okay,thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue

The `additionalProperties` keyword only considers the `properties` and `patternProperties` defined in the immediate subschema where it appears. Since you define the “salary” property only within your `then` and `else` keywords, it is treated as an illegal additional property.

#### Solution

Already introduce the “salary” property in the subschema’s `properties` where the `additionalProperties: false` are defined as well. At least as simple boolean schema `true`.
In other circumstances, one could also include all common attributes that appear in both the `then` and `else` keywords to reduce duplication, but in your particular case that’s hardly an option.

#### Additional Note

Generally speaking, `if`/`then`/`else` should only be used for additional constraints (e.g. `minimum`/`maximum`/`required`) but not to introduce completely new `properties` especially when using `patternProperties` or `additionalProperties`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. In my case, setting additionalProperties: true would not help since it doesn't validate if any incorrect properties entered.